# How can i find all channel ids?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord

```
def SpamRequest():
    channel_id = random.choice(channel_ids)
    r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload, headers=header)
```

How can i find all channel ids whith reqests?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [api docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channels-resource)

```json
{
  "id": "41771983423143937",
  "guild_id": "41771983423143937",
  "name": "general",
  "type": 0,
  "position": 6,
  "permission_overwrites": [],
  "rate_limit_per_user": 2,
  "nsfw": true,
  "topic": "24/7 chat about how to gank Mike #2",
  "last_message_id": "155117677105512449",
  "parent_id": "399942396007890945",
  "default_auto_archive_duration": 60
}
```

example channel. just load in json.

```py
channel_ids = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{guild_id%}/channels", headers=header)
for channel in json.loads(channel_ids.text):
    print(channel['id'])
```

Comment: does not work ):

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: my typo, loadS not load

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: if you want contact me on discord Pąblo # 4316